# Include .net core class library into another .net core class library

Tags: reference, .net-core

I have created a class library with the target framework .NETCoreApp 1.1 with some objects that are common among my classes.

In a second project, also a class library with the target framework .NETCoreApp 1.1 where I want to include the previous created project dll.

How can I do that? I tried to explicitly add the dll in the references, but when I build the second project I get the following error:

> Cannot find project info for 'ProjectPath\ProjectFile.csproj'. This
>   can indicate a missing project reference.

When I check the projects assemblies list I see my dll added there, without the yellow warning icon... What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I am currently using Visual Studio 2017.

And this is the csproj of my second project, the one giving the error:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Common">
      <HintPath>..\Common\bin\Release\netcoreapp1.1\Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Did you use any tooling to do that? VS, CLI, manual edit? also, what does your csproj file contain?

Comment: plus: if outside vs, did you run `dotnet restore`?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added a "Reference" instead of a "Project Reference".
You can correct this by replacing the last `<ItemGroup>` element with:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Common\Common.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I solved the problem I had, but a new one appeared, I have one Console application with the target framework .NETCoreApp 1.1, and I added both projects the same way you told me, as a project, and not as a single dll, the project compiles and runs, but at some point I get this exception: Could not load file or assembly 'Common Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified. You know what can be wrong?

Comment: Oh never mind, I followed your other comment and ran dotnet restore and got it working. Thank you again.